# Datatables custom filtering with server side

Tags: datatables, datatables-1.10, django-datatable

I'm using [DataTables](https://datatables.net/) and also using server side processing (Django).

I have a seperate textfield in which I use it to custom filter data in the DataTable after the table has been rendered already.

The following works just fine (I want to custom filter columns):

```
var table = $('#problem_history').DataTable( {
    "bJQueryUI": true,
    "aaSorting": [[ 1, "desc" ]],
    "aoColumns": [
      // various columns here
    ],
    "processing": true,
    "serverSide": true,
    "ajax": {
      "url": "/getdata",
      "data": {
        "friend_name": 'Robert'
      }
    }  
} );
```

So on the page load (initial load of the DataTable) it filters for 'Robert' just fine. But now I want to programmatically change the data to filter for `"friend_name" == "Sara"`

I already tried the following, the `filteredData` has a correct filtered object but the table itself does not redraw with the new filter.

```
var filteredData = table.column( 4 ).data().filter(
    function ( value, index ) {
        return value == 'Sara' ? true : false;
    }
);
table.draw();
```

I also tried this but no luck:

```
filteredData.draw();
```

How can I achieve this?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 18):

Here is a very nice explanation on how to do it:
https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax.data

I am currently using this code:

```
"ajax": {"url":"/someURL/Backend",
        "data": function ( d ) {
                  return $.extend( {}, d, {
                    "parameterName": $('#fieldIDName').val(),
                    "parameterName2": $('#fieldIDName2').val()
                  } );
        }
}
```

You call it by doing the following:

```
$('#myselectid').change(function (e) {
        table.draw();
});
```

If you want to submit by clicking on the button, change the `.change` to `.click` and make sure that ID is pointing to button's id in a HTML

Comment: somehow I've been missing this for quite some time.  thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You've almost got it. You just need to assign the filter var to
 the data parameter that's passed in the datatables request:

```
"ajax": {
     "url": "/getdata",
     "data": {
     "friend_name": $('#myselectid').val();
    }
}
```

And to filter the data, just call `draw()` on the select change event

```
$('#myselectid').change(function (e) {
        table.fnDraw();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For Basic searches, you should use the [search()](https://datatables.net/reference/api/search()) API:

```js
// Invoke basic search for 'a'
dt.search('a', false)
```

For more complex queries, you can utilize searchBuilder backend by intercepting the ajax call through an open API. Here are some searchBuilder examples:

```js
// Basic example: 
// . (searchable_fields contains 'a' 
//      AND (office = Tokyo AND Salary > 100000) 
//   )
$('#problem_history').on('preXhr.dt', function(e, settings, data){
    data['searchBuilder'] = {
        'criteria': [
            {'data': 'Office', 'origData': 'office', 'type': 'string'
                ,'condition': '='
                ,'value': ["Tokyo"], 'value1': "Tokyo" 
            }
            ,{'data': 'Salary', 'origData': 'salary', 'type': 'num'
                ,'condition': '>'
                ,'value': [100000], 'value1': 100000 
            }
        ]
        ,'logic': 'AND'
    }
})
```

```js
// Complex example:
// . (searchable_fields contains 'a'
//      AND (
//            (office = Tokyo AND Salary > 100000) 
//         OR (office = London AND Salary > 200000)
//      )
//   )
$('#problem_history').on('preXhr.dt', function(e, settings, data){
    data['searchBuilder'] = {
        'criteria': [
            {'criteria': [
                    {'data': 'Office', 'origData': 'office', 'type': 'string'
                        ,'condition': '='
                        ,'value': ["Tokyo"], 'value1': "Tokyo"
                    }
                    ,{'data': 'Salary', 'origData': 'salary', 'type': 'num'
                        ,'condition': '>'
                        ,'value': [100000], 'value1': 100000 
                    }
                ]
                ,'logic': 'AND'
            }
            ,{'criteria': [
                    {'data': 'Office', 'origData': 'office', 'type': 'string'
                        ,'condition': '='
                        ,'value': ["London"], 'value1': "London" 
                    }
                    ,{'data': 'Salary', 'origData': 'salary', 'type': 'num'
                        ,'condition': '>'
                        ,'value': [200000], 'value1': 200000 
                    }
                ]
                ,'logic': 'AND'
            }
        ]
        ,'logic': 'OR'
    }
})
```

SearchBuilder Logic Types:

```
=
!=
contains
starts
ends
<
<=
>
>=
between
null
!null
```

SearchBuilder data value blocks:

- `value: [<val>]` seems to always equal `value1`
- `value2`: For upper bounds of 'between' logic where `value1` would be lower bounds