# Date range inside loop of multiple datatable in the same page

Tags: datatables

I came from the issue [https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/51949/looping-multiple-datatables-on-the-same-page#latest] and found an issue that comes from filtering of dates: if I filter and on change of this date range, it triggers `table.draw()` for the first one if it is inside of the loop of multiple datatable in the same page

My intention is to have the data range to work on each datatable individually

Here is a sample of what I already done
http://live.datatables.net/magokusa/4/edit

HTML

```html
<div class="container">
    <h3>Table 1</h3>
    <div class="input-group input-group-sm">
        <input type="date" id="dateFromupper" placeholder="Date from" value="2017-04-10">
        <div>
            <div>to</div>
        </div>
        <input type="date" id="dateToupper" placeholder="Date to" value="2018-09-10">
    </div>
    <table id="upper" data-action="https://demo.wp-api.org/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?per_page=5" class="display nowrap datatable" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>col1</th>
                <th>col2</th>
                <th>col3</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>

    <hr>
    <h3>Table 2</h3>
    <div class="input-group input-group-sm">
        <input type="date" id="dateFromlower" placeholder="Date from" value="2016-04-10">
        <div>
            <div>to</div>
        </div>
        <input type="date" id="dateTolower" placeholder="Date to" value="2018-09-12">
    </div>
    <table id="lower" data-action="https://css-tricks.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?per_page=5" class="display nowrap datatable" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>col1</th>
                <th>col2</th>
                <th>col3</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
</div>
```

JS

```js
$(document).ready( function () {
    $.each($('.datatable'), function () {
       var dt_id = $(this).attr('id');
       var dt_action = $(this).data('action');

      $.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(
        function (settings, data, dataIndex) {
          var min = $("#dateFrom" + dt_id).val();
          var max = $("#dateTo" + dt_id).val();

          if (min != null && max != null) {
            min = new Date(min);
            max = new Date(max);
            var startDate = new Date(data[1]);
            if (min == null && max == null) {
              return true;
            }
            if (min == null && startDate <= max) {
              return true;
            }
            if (max == null && startDate >= min) {
              return true;
            }
            if (startDate <= max && startDate >= min) {
              return true;
            }
          } else {
            return true;
          }
        }
      );

      $("#dateFrom" + dt_id + ", #dateTo" + dt_id).change(function () {
        table.draw();
      });

       if (dt_action != null) {
           var dt_ajax = dt_action;
           var table = $('#' + dt_id).DataTable({
             ajax: {
               "url": dt_ajax, 
               "dataSrc": ""
             },
             columns: [
               { "data": "status" },
               { "data": "date" },
               { "data": "date_gmt" }, 
             ]
           });
        } else {
           var table = $('.datatable').DataTable({
               retrieve: true,
               responsive: true,
           });
       }
   });
});
```

Comment: Hey @andre, you should add the relevant code to the question. Future visitors have no chance to see what your question is about, and the link will probably not live forever.

Comment: Got it, added in an edit!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you already are declaring two different filters, you can just check if the current draw process is related to the filter itself :

```js
$.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(
  function (settings, data, dataIndex) {
    if (settings.sInstance != dt_id) return true 
    ...
  }
)
```

Comment: Mmmmm, I don't understand, I tried to apply on the live code and it did not worked, it just blew away the current existent filter

Comment: @AndréNakazato, Yes, because you also had other issues with the code :) here is a more functional version -> **http://live.datatables.net/mohepika/1/edit** (the lower data source was bad and you did not had control over the table instances)