# Datatables daterange filtering function conflicting with searchbox filter

Tags: jquery, filter, datatables, daterangepicker

I have created a date range filter for my datatable that is working as expected. 
However now the search box is not working anymore as before.
I assume that it now uses my custom function that is limited on the date column. How can I specify that my custom search function is only used when the date range apply event is triggered, else the default behavior retains?

Here is the code with working date-range filter on codepen.io
https://codepen.io/bintux/pen/rgYeyp

```js
$(function() {
 var table = $("#table_1").DataTable();

 // Date range vars
 minDateFilter = "";
 maxDateFilter = "";

 $("#daterange").daterangepicker();
 $("#daterange").on("apply.daterangepicker", function(ev, picker) {
  minDateFilter = Date.parse(picker.startDate.format("YYYY-MM-DD"));
  maxDateFilter = Date.parse(picker.endDate.format("YYYY-MM-DD"));
  table.draw();
 });

 $.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(function(settings, data, dataIndex) {
  var date = Date.parse(data[1]); 

  if (
   (isNaN(minDateFilter) && isNaN(maxDateFilter)) ||
   (isNaN(minDateFilter) && date <= maxDateFilter) ||
   (minDateFilter <= date && isNaN(maxDateFilter)) ||
   (minDateFilter <= date && date <= maxDateFilter)
  ) {
   return true;
  }
  return false;
 });
});
```

```html
<table id="table_1" >
 <thead>
  <tr>
   <th>Col1.</th>
   <th>Date</th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
   <tr>
   <td>Set 1</td>
   <td data-order="1558358405">20 May 2019</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>Set2</td>
   <td data-order="1558357779">20 May 2019</td>
  </tr>
....
```

Can I pass on arguments to the draw() function when the daterange apply is triggered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [davidkonrad](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1407478/davidkonrad) answer on a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29836857/jquery-datatable-filtering-so-confusing), I was able to solve it.
Just moved the filter function into the daterange apply event function.

```
 $("#daterange").on("apply.daterangepicker", function(ev, picker) {
  minDateFilter = Date.parse(picker.startDate);
  maxDateFilter = Date.parse(picker.endDate);

  $.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(function(settings, data, dataIndex) {
  var date = Date.parse(data[1]);

  if (
   (isNaN(minDateFilter) && isNaN(maxDateFilter)) ||
   (isNaN(minDateFilter) && date <= maxDateFilter) ||
   (minDateFilter <= date && isNaN(maxDateFilter)) ||
   (minDateFilter <= date && date <= maxDateFilter)
  ) {
   return true;
  }
  return false;
 });
 table.draw();
});
```

[Updated Codepen Example](https://codepen.io/bintux/pen/rgYeyp)