# How to display/search data in jQUERY Datatable if the whole column data matches searched string?

Tags: jquery, datatable, datatables, datatables-1.10

I'm using `datatables` library and I have a column in my table containing value 'John Mary'.
How can I filter out this record from the results when either 'John' or 'Mary' is searched?
The 'John Mary' record should not be part of output. It should only come up when 'John Mary' is searched

Comment: are you using serverside searching ?

Comment: No. I am not using server side searching

Comment: check this  https://stackoverflow.com/a/22841517/2996989

Comment: I want to search on whole column data not on all words in columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comments are correct, you should create your own filter for this. Here is one that require full match in any column, it is also case sensitive :

```
$.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(function(settings, data, dataIndex) {
  var term = $('.dataTables_filter input').val();
  for (var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
    if (data[i] == term || term == '') return true
  }
})
```